# Python MetaTrader5 indicators

Tags: python, metatrader5

I'm using Metatrader5 module for python and this is my code

'''
    #python

```
from datetime import datetime
import MetaTrader5 as mt5

# display data on the MetaTrader 5 package
print("MetaTrader5 package author: ", mt5.__author__)
print("MetaTrader5 package version: ", mt5.__version__)

# import the 'pandas' module for displaying data obtained in the tabular form
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)  # number of columns to be displayed
pd.set_option('display.width', 1500)  # max table width to display
# import pytz module for working with time zone
import pytz

# establish connection to MetaTrader 5 terminal
if not mt5.initialize():
print("initialize() failed")
mt5.shutdown()

# set time zone to UTC
timezone = pytz.timezone("Etc/UTC")
# create 'datetime' object in UTC time zone to avoid the implementation of a local time zone offset
utc_from = datetime(2020, 1, 10, tzinfo=timezone)
# get 10 EURUSD H4 bars starting from 01.10.2020 in UTC time zone
rates = mt5.copy_rates_from("EURUSD", mt5.TIMEFRAME_H4, utc_from, 10)

# shut down connection to the MetaTrader 5 terminal
mt5.shutdown()
# display each element of obtained data in a new line
print("Display obtained data 'as is'")
for rate in rates:
print(rate)
# create DataFrame out of the obtained data
rates_frame = pd.DataFrame(rates)
# convert time in seconds into the datetime format
rates_frame['time'] = pd.to_datetime(rates_frame['time'], unit='s')

# display data
print("\nDisplay dataframe with data")
print(rates_frame)
```

'''

My question is s there any easy way to calculate stock indicators like RSI and MFI and other indicators using this module?

Answer (score 2):

No. Its possible if using other modules though.

Here is a method using another that could achieve it: 
https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/5691

Alternatively, you can pull the data from MT5 and throw it in TA-lib for analysis. TA-lib consumes the data and provides values for the indicators outside MT5.

Check out TA-lib: https://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/

Answer (score 1):

Since your data will be in a pandas df, I would check out pandas-ta, https://pypi.org/project/pandas-ta, all technical indicators. Also, thats a lot of code to pull your data, this is what I use;

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

mt.initialize()

df = pd.DataFrame( mt.copy_rates_range( '@MNQ', #micro nasd100
                                        mt.TIMEFRAME_D1, 
                                        datetime( 2022, 1, 1 ), 
                                        datetime.now() ) )

# manipulate as you please

mt.shutdown()
```

and i didnt like the GMT+2 timezone used by metatrader at first but Ive found its easier to get used to it as the date change is timed to the daily futures market open at 5pm central, which in GMT+2 is day+1 00:00.